# how to convert one navigation controller to a split view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a navigation controller with a tableview inside on iphone version. Basically when I tap some row in this table A, sub-tableview controller A1 or A2 is pushed. Now on iPad, I need to show A1 or A2 in detailview in a splitview controller. How should I transform them? It's not in a root view controller.

I tried put my 'table A' view controller in master VC and a blank navigation controller in detail VC in the splitview, but how can I tell detail VC to show what after I select some row in table A?

Thanks...I tried but can't find any solution. I thought it would be pretty easy.

Comment: You can put table A in the left side of a split view. Then on the right side of the split view, you can put a container view that will show A1 or A2 depending on what was selected in table A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the template master-detail project that Xcode creates?  It demonstrates the approach pretty clearly.  Specifically have a look at the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method of the masterViewController

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;
    }
}
```

Essentially your master view controller has a property that holds a reference to your detail view controller.  This allows you to send a message to the detail view controller when it needs to display an object